# console returning different heights in ie, ff and chrome for the same element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set .outerHeight(true) on the element #inner but at the moment it returns height values

ie: 304
ff: 317
chrome: 289

can anyone explain where I might be going wrong with this?

JS

```
var wH = $(window).height(),
    wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
    inner = $('#inner'),
    innerH = inner.outerHeight(true),
    more = inner.find('.more'),
    close = inner.find('.close'),
    titleH = $('#title').outerHeight(true),
    excerpt = $('.excerpt'),
    excerptH = excerpt.outerHeight(true),
    lowerH = $('.lower').outerHeight(true),
    upper = inner.find('.upper'),
    footerH = $('#footer').height()
    body = $('body');

// Set #wrapper off page
wrapper.css('bottom', -innerH);

// Store tier1 calculation as data attribute
wrapper.data('tier1', -innerH+titleH+footerH);
console.log(innerH);
//console.log(-innerH+titleH+footerH);
// Animate #wrapper above #footer
wrapper.delay(500).animate({ bottom: wrapper.data('tier1') }, 400);
```

CSS

```
body{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;overflow: hidden;}
h1{text-align:center;width:600px;margin:0 auto;padding:20px 0 45px;font-size:28px;font-weight:bold;line-height:26px;}
p{margin-bottom:20px;}


#tiers{background:#f2f2f2;height:100%;}
#wrapper{width:100%;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;background:#dedede;}
#inner{width:840px;margin:0 auto;}
.upper{display:none;}
.upper p{margin-bottom:0;}
.col{width:410px;}
.btn{background: #000000;color: #FFFFFF;display: block;font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;width:30px;height:30px;text-align:center;line-height:30px;position: absolute;text-decoration: none;}
.more{top:20px;right:20px;}
.close{display:none;top:60px;right:20px;}
.excerpt{display: block;}
```

HTML

```
<body class="tier1">

  <div id="tiers">
      <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="inner" class="clearfix">
          <a href="#" class="close btn">-</a>
          <a href="#" class="more btn">+</a>
          <div class="lower">
            <h1 id="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
            <p class="excerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
              cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
              proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
              cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
              proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="upper">
            <div class="col left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
            <div class="col right"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>




</body>
```

Link to page: http://bit.ly/IA65Mb

Kyle

Answer (score 0):

There are a few differences I was able to spot:

- `p` has a 20px `margin-bottom` which propagates to `#inner` in chrome. I don't remember the details of this feature but I think I heard once that it's actually correct behavior. I think only chrome has it. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/tT5Wh/2/)
- for some reason `#excerpt` has different heights in ff and chrome - maybe there are slight differences in text rendering?

I think fixing the first issue would solve the problem you're having though. Getting exact same result cross-browser is an overkill.